# sqlalchemy - AttributeError(key) missing key when it actually is in columnCollection

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My engine has a property `dMeta`, which return the engines meta, then I have a class with an method called `table` which basically does this:

```
def table(meta):
    return Table('table1',meta,autoload=True,schema=genShema())
```

I'm auto-loading the table:

```
t = SomeClass.table(engine.dMeta)
sql = select([t.c.ID, t.c.OPIS, t.c.IDG,
                         func.left(t.c.ID,2).label("Ident"),
                         (func.left(t.c.ID,2).label('Ident2')+' '+t.c.OPIS).label("show_as")])\
                .where(t.c.ATRIBUT=="VPFA")
```

SQLAlchemy gives me the error of:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    try:
        return self._data[key]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError(key)
```

The key is `ID`, the `self._data contains` 'ID' = {Column} which is a `table1.ID` and if I put the `self._data[key]` I get the correct value, no error, so what is the problem here?

Even after I rerun the code a couple of times, sometimes it breaks, sometimes it doesn't :/

Comment: Are you changing the table somewhere ? How do you generate the schema ?

Comment: SomeClass.table(engine.dMeta) -> this calls the table method of the class. Returns the autoloaded table.

genShema() returns None if no argument is passed, else it pusts '.dbo' at the end if the db is mssql

Comment: Check the capitalization of the column name in the db

Comment: Its the same, the thing is, i put a breakpoint on the raise AttributeError(key) line, and then i put into watcher the return self._data[key] and it works fine, no errors. It seems that in that moment he does not have any keys in _data. If i refresh the page to trigger the code again it works fine, but not always, kinda random.

Comment: Maybe the tables are not initialized when you access them? Is that a possibility ?

Comment: Is any progress on this? I have the same issue

Comment: Can we get the full traceback for this issue? Also this select is weird. `(func.left(t.c.ID,2).label('Ident2')+' '+t.c.OPIS).label("show_as"))`. You're attempting to concat without using `func.concat()` and labeling both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not concating correctly and that's throwing the error try this.

```
sql = select([t.c.ID, t.c.OPIS, t.c.IDG, func.left(t.c.ID,2).label("Ident"), func.concat(func.left(t.c.ID,2), literal(" "), t.c.OPIS)]).where(t.c.ATRIBUT=="VPFA")
```